# Centering responsive header - wordpress blog

Tags: html, css, wordpress, blogs

I've tried several methods but can't seem to get each part of this accomplished. I've made a wordpress blog for someone and she was happy with it but recently wanted the header changed. I had it wide and she wanted it boxed/centered. The header contains logo, nav and two images on the left that the client wanted placed there for looks, basically. The blog is responsive and once the screen gets to a certain point, the header matches the container of the rest of the page. But on fullscreen laptop/desktop, it still starts out much wider with just a bit of padding on each side. When I pad it to the right width, then it gets to small when the screen changes. I want it to be the same width of the main slider and container at all times.

The blog is at http://www.allloveblog.com

The CSS I have for the header currently:

```
.fusion-header{
position:relative;
display:block;
/*width:100%;*/
/*padding-left:162px;
padding-right:160px;*/
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
}

.fusion-header-wrapper{
position:relative;
display:block;
width:100%;
float:center;

}
```

If you change your browser window you can see where the change takes place and it becomes stick as soon as it's the width of the other containers, I just need it to start at the width of the container.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you have to do is this:

```
.fusion-header-wrapper {
    max-width: 1160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In case you need to overwrite some CSS rules just add `body` before the class. This way your rule will be prioritized and you can easily identify your rules. Like this:

```
body .fusion-header-wrapper {
    max-width: 1160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

EXPLANATION
Basically what you needed to do is set a width limit to the header matching the main's width limit `max-width: 1160px;` and obviously center the header with `margin: 0 auto;`

`#main` has 30px padding left and right.
Inside `#main` we have `.fusion-row` with `max-width: 1100px;`
Inside `.fusion-header-wrapper` we have `.fusion-header` with 30px padding left and right.
So if you set `max-width: 1100px;`you will notice that you need to add 60 more px because of the paddings on other divs.

P.S. Make sure you create a Child Theme for editing the existing WP Theme.